# Facebook insights for websites does not match on-site Facebook button counts

Tags: facebook-graph-api, social-networking, facebook-insights

I use Facebook Insights for websites and Facebook buttons on my site.  However, the data reported by the two do not match.  It always seems to be the case that the count reported by the buttons is significantly higher than the count reported in Facebook Insights.

For example, this page http://www.appmyworld.com/blog/top-5-iphone-and-ipad-apps-of-the-week-10412.html has a count of 52 for Facebook which is made up of 19 likes, 21 shares and 12 comments according to AddThis and confirmed by http://sharedcount.com

However, going into Facebook Insights for my website and looking at that specific page it shows only 4 total actions which is made up of 1 like and 3 shares.  At the very least I would expect it to show a total count of 40 made up of 19 likes and 21 shares (I'm not sure it would track the 12 comments).

Any thoughts on why this may be happening?  My concern is if our website is not getting credit for the Facebook activity?

Comment: Are you sure the insights aren't showing a specific timeframe?

Comment: Thanks for the thought, I went back and double checked the times but no luck.

Comment: Wondering if there is something wrong in my site's code or if I need to do something extra to link the site to the insights?  I have my FB app_id in the site code correctly (I think) and thought that was all there was to it.  Another page shows 33 count on the FB buttons (13 likes, 17 shares, 3 comments) but only 10 count in insights (2 likes & 8 shares) http://www.appmyworld.com/blog/top-5-iphone-and-ipad-games-of-the-week-10312.html  It seems like the count returned by the open graph API is higher than what insights shows.

Answer (score 0):

Which panel are you getting the Facebook insights figures from? Make sure your app ID is correct on your page, and make sure you're accounting for the proper time frame. You can read about how to use Facebook Insights here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/insights/

Comment: Steps I take: 1) go to https://www.facebook.com/insights/ 2) click on site name 3) Click on "select page" 4) Enter URL of page I am interested in 5) Look in the "site engagement" panel for the relevant stats.  That is where I get 1 like and 3 shares for the page http://www.appmyworld.com/blog/top-5-iphone-and-ipad-apps-of-the-week-10412.html but if I plug that page into this URL https://graph.facebook.com/http://www.appmyworld.com/blog/top-5-iphone-and-ipad-apps-of-the-week-10412.html I get 52 & 52 matches with AddThis and http://sharedcount.com made up of 19 likes, 21 shares & 12 comments

Comment: Also, time frame shows October 2 - 7 (example article was published October 4 without significant traffic on october 8th) and app ID on website is the same app ID as the Facebook app I used to claim my website for insights.  One thing that did happen is the app ID was removed from the websites root page due to a bug (it is due to be added back tomorrow) but the app ID is still on the article page.